# Word for a person who wants to impose his rules everywhere or advise

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, american-english, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

My colleague has always something to advise, whatever you eat or play and he sometimes tries to dig out information from you and again advise on it. I just hate to get any feedback from him: if what I am eating is good or bad or how many people I am inviting on my daughter's birthday (none of his matter)!

I am looking for a word for that type of person.

Comment: The verb is *advise*. *Advice* is a noun.

Comment: I agree with you. I just posted without review.

Comment: _Opinionated_ works.  _Bossy_ also works for this meaning.  Admittedly, there are nuances to whichever word you use, but in AmE these would convey your meaning well.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Comment: Around here, a person who constantly advises others might be called an _ELUcidator_.

Answer (score 12):

**Officious**: [objectionably aggressive in offering one's unrequested and unwanted services, help, or advice; meddlesome: an officious person. 2. marked by or proceeding from such forwardness: officious interference.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/officious)

Comment: That's the word I was looking for! This is the best answer.

Comment: @Will Is it the _best answer_? Or are you being _officious_? ;)

Comment: Haha, well played `:)`

Answer (score 7):

Consider “**busybody**”.

And here's a better translation of your description:

> My colleague always gives unwanted advice. He's always prying and commenting on things, like what I choose to eat, or what music I like. I don't like when he volunteers his opinion on things that aren't any of his business. He's such a **busybody**.

Comment: This, or "bossy" to put a bit more of the "imposing his own rules" feeling into it.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you are thinking about: **[Mr. know it all](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mr.%20know-it-all)**

Someone who believes they've got the answer to every question even if the question hasn't been asked or if they really don't have the answer (... but of course they believe they do). This is not a shy individual, but rather someone whose ego is over flowing primarily through their mouth, but seems to have come from the other end of their digestive system.

Comment: In my experience, the "Mr." is optional.

Answer (score 2):

Stickybeak, perhaps?  Though that might not be as commonly used in America as in Australia.

Comment: Never heard this before (from the UK) but I like it :)

Comment: I like it too! But busybody probably does have a more negative feel towards it.

Answer (score 1):

Just *imposing* would carry the meaning. "He is imposing", or "he is an imposing person" means that he tends to impose his opinion on people.

Comment: I think imposing today is meant more often to describe someone with great presence: "the young squire stood before the king, his company of knights standing at his side, imposing in their gleaming armor and silent reverie." In this case it's almost the opposite of what you suggest, because the imposing people are silent, rather than nosey.

Comment: +1. I like it. it's simple, elegant, to the point. verb (used with object), imposed, imposing.  

1. to lay on or set as something to be borne, endured, obeyed, fulfilled, paid, etc.: to impose taxes.
2.to put or set by or as if by authority: 
to impose one's personal preference on others.
3.to obtrude or thrust (oneself, one's company, etc.) upon others. 
4.to pass or palm off fraudulently or deceptively: 
*He imposed his pretentious books on the public.*

Answer (score 1):

Meddlesome or "know it all" works probably best for informal and non-work related situations.
If it is someone who likes to force his/her way of working/thinking on to work-related issues officious seems to me more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

One term that seems to apply here is *buttinsky* (sometimes spelled *buttinski* or *butinski*):

> *n.* One who is prone to butting in; a meddler
>
> Source: [theFreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/buttinsky)

It's slang, and it may not be common outside the US, but it might work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

This requires the use of metaphor, but would generally be understood in context. The image is of a passenger fussing, unsolicited, about a driver's speed, chosen route, follow distance, etc.

> [backseat driver](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/backseat-driver)
>
> noun [ C ] US /ˈbækˌsit ˈdrɑɪ·vər/
>
> a person who gives unwanted advice or criticism, esp. to the driver of a car

Answer (score 0):

A person that wants to impose his rules everywhere and advise is a [**peremptory**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Peremptory?s=t) person.

> leaving no opportunity for denial or refusal; imperious; positive or assertive in speech, tone, manner, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is a control freak, a person who feels an obsessive need to exercise control over themselves and others and to take command of any situation.

Answer (score -1):

The word you are looking for is "condescending". It's a person who thinks he knows everything and gives advice without someone asking for it.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, can you please add sources to your answer to substantiate your claim. You can also have a look at the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out about good answers.